# How can I mock Webpack's require.context in Jest?

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

Suppose I have the following module:

```
var modulesReq = require.context('.', false, /\.js$/);
modulesReq.keys().forEach(function(module) {
  modulesReq(module);
});
```

Jest complains because it doesn't know about `require.context`:

```
 FAIL  /foo/bar.spec.js (0s)
● Runtime Error
  - TypeError: require.context is not a function
```

How can I mock it? I tried using [`setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#setuptestframeworkscriptfile-string) Jest configuration but the tests can't see any changes that I've made in `require`.

Comment: Did you found your answer ?

Answer (score 33):

I had the same problem, then I've made a 'solution'.

I'm pretty sure that this is not the best choice. I ended up stopping using  it, by the points answered here:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/517
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2298

But if you really need it, you should include the polyfill below in every file that you call it (not on the tests file itself, because the `require` will be no global overridden in a Node environment).

```
// This condition actually should detect if it's an Node environment
if (typeof require.context === 'undefined') {
  const fs = require('fs');
  const path = require('path');

  require.context = (base = '.', scanSubDirectories = false, regularExpression = /\.js$/) => {
    const files = {};

    function readDirectory(directory) {
      fs.readdirSync(directory).forEach((file) => {
        const fullPath = path.resolve(directory, file);

        if (fs.statSync(fullPath).isDirectory()) {
          if (scanSubDirectories) readDirectory(fullPath);

          return;
        }

        if (!regularExpression.test(fullPath)) return;

        files[fullPath] = true;
      });
    }

    readDirectory(path.resolve(__dirname, base));

    function Module(file) {
      return require(file);
    }

    Module.keys = () => Object.keys(files);

    return Module;
  };
}
```

With this function, you don't need to change any `require.context` call, it will execute with the same behavior as it would (if it's on webpack it will just use the original implementation, and if it's inside Jest execution, with the polyfill function).

Comment: what would you suggest to use instead of 'fs'? I don't have it in my project and when I tried to install, I had many other errors

Comment: fs is a native package that comes with NodeJS. You don't need to install it. It will work just by adding the require('fs') directly since your Jest tests run in a NodeJS env.

Comment: Not sure what is going on with my setup, but even when `require()`ing this polyfill in the file, right before using `require.context` and `throw()`ing inside the function to see that it was running, `require.context` is always undefined.

Comment: All things considering, this is not a good solution for anything other than personal project. Please consider using the solution provided by thompsonsj in enterprise applications.

Answer (score 33):

If you are using Babel, look at [babel-plugin-require-context-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-require-context-hook). Configuration instructions for Storybook are available at [Storyshots | Configure Jest to work with Webpack's require.context()](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/addons/storyshots/storyshots-core#configure-jest-to-work-with-webpacks-requirecontext), but they are not Storyshots/Storybook specific.

To summarise:

Install the plugin.

```
yarn add babel-plugin-require-context-hook --dev
```

Create a file `.jest/register-context.js` with the following contents:

```
import registerRequireContextHook from 'babel-plugin-require-context-hook/register';
registerRequireContextHook();
```

Configure Jest (the file depends on where you are storing your Jest configuration, e.g. `package.json`):

```
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/.jest/register-context.js']
```

Add the plugin to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["..."],
  "plugins": ["..."],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["require-context-hook"]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, add it to `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true)

  const presets = [...]
  const plugins = [...]

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {    
    plugins.push("require-context-hook")    
  }

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  }
}
```

It may be worth noting that using `babel.config.js` rather than `.babelrc` may cause issues. For example, I found that when I defined the `require-context-hook` plugin in `babel.config.js`:

- Jest 22 didn't pick it up;
- Jest 23 picked it up; but
- `jest --coverage` didn't pick it up (perhaps Istanbul isn't up to speed with Babel 7?).

In all cases, a `.babelrc` configuration was fine.

---

Remarks on [Edmundo Rodrigues's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332094/how-can-i-mock-webpacks-require-context-in-jest/42191018#42191018)

This `babel-plugin-require-context-hook` plugin uses code that is similar to Edmundo Rodrigues's answer here. Props to Edmundo! Because the plugin is implemented as a Babel plugin, it avoids static analysis issues. e.g. With Edmundo's solution, Webpack warns:

```
Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
```

Despite the warnings, Edmundo's solution is the most robust because it doesn't depend on Babel.

Comment: I posted this on [github](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/2487)
It is a huge hack, but maybe helps others who could also not get it working with babel and jest configs

Comment: I have seen these instructions on Storybook, followed them and get a new error where my JSX tags cant be recognoised... 

`(0, _react2.storiesOf)('.../...', module).add('...', () => <_common.Card>`
the error i get is....
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

where `Card` is a custom react component, has been tested with jsx div as well

Comment: Please note that the issue with the `babel.config.js` is no longer the case, and the way it is used here in `.babelrc`, can also be used in the `babel.config.js`.

Thank you @thompsonsj

Comment: Please change `process.env.ENV_NODE` to `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Answer (score 33):

After spending some hours trying each of the answers above. I would like to contribute.

Adding `babel-plugin-transform-require-context` plugin to `.babelrc` for test env fixed all the issues.

Install - `babel-plugin-transform-require-context` here https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-require-context (available with `yarn` too)

Now add plugin to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-require-context"]
    }
  }
}
```

It will simply transform `require-context` for test env into dummy `fn` calls so that code can run safely.

Comment: The plugin name should be `transform-require-context`

Comment: Correct @Yael Thanks for informing, I missed updating it

Comment: note to future readers: this does not fix the issue per se, it just works around it by resolving an empty context. if you have code which still needs require.context to work- this answer won't help you.

Comment: This actually suits my needs. Thanks.

Comment: You saved me really. Moreover, if your project doesn't contains a .babelrc you may add the configurations inside the exported configurations array of your babel.config.js in the project root folder. Thank you again

Comment: I had to run "jest --clearCache" to make it work

Answer (score 26):

Extract the call to a separate module:

```
// src/js/lib/bundle-loader.js
/* istanbul ignore next */
module.exports = require.context('bundle-loader?lazy!../components/', false, /.*\.vue$/)
```

Use the new module in the module where you extracted it from:

```
// src/js/lib/loader.js
const loadModule = require('lib/bundle-loader')
```

Create a mock for the newly created bundle-loader module:

```
// test/unit/specs/__mocks__/lib/bundle-loader.js
export default () => () => 'foobar'
```

Use the mock in your test:

```
// test/unit/specs/lib/loader.spec.js
jest.mock('lib/bundle-loader')
import Loader from 'lib/loader'

describe('lib/loader', () => {
  describe('Loader', () => {
    it('should load', () => {
      const loader = new Loader('[data-module]')
      expect(loader).toBeInstanceOf(Loader)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: @Bartekus If you say it is not a good solution (or downvote), please also be so kind to explain, why it is not a good solution in your opinion.

Comment: @ borisdiakur indeed, you are right, and on the second though, despite the fact that your solution is not necessarily what I would use in enterprise grade software, it is NOT incorrect.

As such, I'm actually doing the community disservice by down-voting it all together, as I would use this in my personal projects, or enterprise software which uses webpack but does not utilizes Babel along side (it's certainly not impossible for this type of scenario to occur).

That being said, my answer is locked in, but if you edit it (even if you do not change the content) I'll remove my down vote.

Answer (score 9):

Alrighty! I had major issues with this and managed to come to a solution that worked for me by using a combination of other answers and the Docs. (Took me a good day though)

For anyone else who is struggling:

Create a file called bundle-loader.js and add something like:

```
module.exports = {
  importFiles: () => {
    const r = require.context(<your_path_to_your_files>)
    <your_processing> 
    return <your_processed_files>
  }
}
```

In your code import like:

```
import bundleLoader from '<your_relative_Path>/bundle-loader'
```

Use like

```
let <your_var_name> = bundleLoader.importFiles()
```

In your test file right underneath other imports:

```
jest.mock('../../utils/bundle-loader', () => ({
  importFiles: () => {
    return <this_will_be_what_you_recieve_in_the_test_from_import_files>
  }
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, nothing else worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Installing

> babel-plugin-transform-require-context

package and adding the plugin in the .babelrc resolved the issue for me.
Refer to the documentation here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-require-context

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and fastest way to solve this problem will be to install [require-context.macro](https://github.com/storybookjs/require-context.macro)

```
npm install --save-dev require-context.macro
```

then just replace:

```
var modulesReq = require.context('.', false, /\.js$/);
```

with:

```
var modulesReq = requireContext('.', false, /\.js$/);
```

Thats it, you should be good to go!
Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Simple and just tested it works, doesn't use configuration overriding, cra safe, and TypeScript safe.

Comment: `context = requireContext(__dirname + '/../../api/rest/validSQL', true, /.json$/)` please note that [passing variables](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9300) can cause issues. My build failed under different root content so adding `__dirname` and using relative rooting after that worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation problems not mentioned:

1. Jest prevents out-of-scope variables in `mock`, like `__dirname`.
2. Create React App limits Babel and Jest customization. You need to use `src/setupTests.js` which is run before every test.
3. `fs` is not supported in the browser. You will need something like browserFS. Now your app has file system support, just for dev.
4. Potential race condition. Export after this import. One of your `require.context` imports includes that export. I'm sure `require` takes care of this, but now we are adding a lot of `fs` work on top of it.
5. Type checking.

Either #4 or #5 created undefined errors. Type out the imports, no more errors. No more concerns about what can or can't be imported and where.

Motivation for all this? Extensibility. Keeping future modifications limited to one new file. Publishing separate modules is a better approach.

If there's an easier way to import, node would do it. Also this smacks of premature optimization. You end up scrapping everything anyways because you're now using an industry leading platform or utility.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **Jest** with **test-utils** in **Vue**.

Install these packages:

> @vue/cli-plugin-babel

and

> babel-plugin-transform-require-context

Then define `babel.config.js` at the root of the project with this configuration:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);

    const presets = [
        '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
    ];

    const plugins = [];

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
        plugins.push('transform-require-context');
    }

    return {
        presets,
        plugins
    };
};
```

This will check if the current process is initiated by Jest and if so, it mocks all the `require.context` calls.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with an ejected create-react-app project
and no one from the answers above helped me...

My solution were to copy to `config/babelTransform.js` the follwoing:

```js
module.exports = babelJest.createTransformer({
  presets: [
    [
      require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app'),
      {
        runtime: hasJsxRuntime ? 'automatic' : 'classic',
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins:["transform-require-context"],
  babelrc: false,
  configFile: false,
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Simpleset Solution for this

Just Do

```
var modulesReq = require.context && require.context('.', false, /\.js$/);
if(modulesReq) {
modulesReq.keys().forEach(function(module) {
  modulesReq(module);
});
```

}

So Here I have added extra check if require.context is defined then only execute By Doing this jest will no longer complain

Comment: Yes, but you will also lose the imports in Jest, and by extension lose the ability to test anything related to those modules.