# Fix unit test Error using Jest in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, frontend

I'm creating a unit test on some code in React. But there is some action that didn't seem to work.

Let say I have a testing.js containing at the begenning:

```
const images = require.context('../../../media/promotions', true);
```

This is the unit test i'm trying ( testing.test.js ) :

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { Testing } from '../../src/components/Testing';




let wrapper, instance;

beforeAll(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(
        <Testing />
    );
    instance = wrapper.instance();
});

describe('Testing', () => {
it('renders without crashing', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
})
```

But the application crushes and this is the error that I get :

```
TypeError: require.context is not a function
```

Comment: `require.context` is a webpack feature, it's not available in Jest tests, where you don't use webpack

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mock Webpack's require.context in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332094/how-can-i-mock-webpacks-require-context-in-jest)

Comment: @PatrickHund I'm looking for a React Js answer and hopefully an update ; I already took a look at that question but I didn't find any useful answers

Comment: I think it doesn't really have anything to do with React, it's a problem with webpack and Jest. React is just a library for rendering user interfaces, it has nothing to do with module loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the library:

`import requireContext from 'require-context.macro';`

And then require them this way:

`const images = requireContext('../../../media/promotions', true);`