# getting require.context is not a function while runnning tests after upgrading to React 16.9

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, enzyme, babel-polyfill

I am getting the below error

> " Test suite failed to run TypeError: require.context is not a
>   function"

after upgrading to react 16.9 from React 16.4. I have tried replacing the @babel-polyfill with corejs/stable but no use. Only test cases are breaking and application is working fine. I am using jest enzyme for tests.

Also, after upgrading its not react mock tests from my '**mocks**' folder at root level.

Comment: `require.context` is a webpack thing, therefore it is not exists in jest. Read this for solutions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332094/how-can-i-mock-webpacks-require-context-in-jest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock Webpack's require.context in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38332094/how-can-i-mock-webpacks-require-context-in-jest)