# Vue unit test - dynamic components & child components & require.context

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-router, vue-test-utils

I am entering the world of application testing and I have some doubts about how to test, mainly because of the child components.

Basically, the first tests I'm trying to run is to cover whether the listing pages have the right data.

During this test 3 problems are happening to me.

First problem

> `require.context is not a function`

In the settings of the vue-router I have the import of the middleware of each route dynamically, and when running the test this error appears to me. Is there any way to resolve this?

Config vue-router

```
...

const resolveMiddlewares = ( requireContext ) => {
    return requireContext.keys()
        .map(file =>
            [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
        ).reduce((guards, [name, guard]) => ({
            ...guards, [name]: guard.default
        }), {})
}

...

const routeMiddlewares = resolveMiddlewares( require.context( './middlewares', false, /.*\.js$/ ) );
```

If I comment this line `const routeMiddlewares = ...` the test continues, and the second problem arises.

Second problem

> `[vue-test-utils]: find did not return .table__users__col__1, cannot call text() on empty Wrapper`

I am trying to replicate the structure of the components that are used for a listing. As you can see below, the structure is as follows. I have a parent component, `baseTable`, which will have two child components, `columnHeader`, which will fill the headers of the table and another that will be called dynamically, according to the route the user is navigating. In this example, imagine that the route is from the users page.

components structure

```
baseTable
  |- columnHeader
  |- rowRoute
```

In the test I am doing the following:

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import baseTable from '@/components/bundles/tables/baseTable';
import getters from '@/store/modules/globals/user/getters';
import actions from '@/store/modules/globals/user/actions';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use( Vuex );

describe( 'Lists', () => {

    it( 'Users list', () => {
        // mock users
        const users = [{
            id: 1,
            name: 'User 1',
            email: 'user@email.com',
            role: 'Admin'
        }];

        const wrapper = shallowMount( baseTable, {
            propsData: {
                url: 'users',
                headers: [ null, 'name', 'email', 'role' ],
                fields: users,
                row: 'Users',
            },
            stubs: [ 'router-link' ],
            mocks: {
                $t: ( msg ) => msg
            },
            getters,
            actions
        });

        console.log( wrapper.html() );

        // validates if the fields are being filled in the appropriate places.
        // table__users__col__1 - class from dynamic child ( rowUsers ).
        expect( wrapper.find( '.table__users__col__1' ).text() ).toBe( user.name );
        expect( wrapper.find( '.table__users__col__2' ).text() ).toBe( user.email );
        expect( wrapper.find( '.table__users__col__3' ).text() ).toBe( user.role );
    })

})
```

I noticed that the log that is in the code, just returns me the HTML of the parent component, baseTable and I don't know if that's why the problem exists.

Third problem

> - [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined"
> - [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined"

This is because in the `rowUsers` component I have a child component, `baseAvatar`, in which the avatars are stored in the store, in order to avoid unnecessary requests.

I tried to get getters and actions through the wrapper, however it didn't work.

Test:

```
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import getters from '@/store/modules/globals/user/getters';
import actions from '@/store/modules/globals/user/actions';
import rowUsers from '@/components/dynamic/tables/rowUsers';

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use( Vuex );

describe( 'List', () => {

    it( 'User list', () => {
        // mock user
        const user = {
            id: 1,
            name: 'User 1',
            email: 'user@email.com',
            role: 'Admin'
        };

        const wrapper = shallowMount( rowUsers, {
            propsData: {
                url: 'users',
                headers: [ null, 'name', 'email', 'role' ],
                row: user,
            },
            stubs: [ 'router-link' ],
            mocks: {
                $t: ( msg ) => msg
            },
            getters,
            actions
        });

        // validates if the fields are being filled in the appropriate places.
        expect( wrapper.find( '.table__users__col__1' ).text() ).toBe( user.name );
        expect( wrapper.find( '.table__users__col__2' ).text() ).toBe( user.email );
        expect( wrapper.find( '.table__users__col__3' ).text() ).toBe( user.role );
    })

})
```

If i comment on the import of the `baseAvatar` component in the `rowUsers` component, the test passes and gives me ok.

some help?

Comment: You are asking multiple things in a single question !

Comment: First problem can get solved using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61137440/7358308